# Problem with UT8 in comments date

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

In this [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17483/594]), a username with UTF8 characters has the date split in two parts.

> [image]

Comment: could you maybe add a link to the post where the comment is?

Comment: Sorry it got messed up in my editing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

[image: screenshot]

The HTML element containing the timestamp has now the "dir" attribute set to "ltr."

[image: screenshot]